# the equation of plane pass through three points

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra

find the equation of plane pass through three points:
A(-5,0,4)
B(0,-4,4)
D(-5.0.0)

and

O (0,0,0)
E (0,-4,0)
G (0,0,4)

Comment: Questions that look like they’re simply a pasted-in homework assignment that show no effort of your own to solve them are not accepted well on this site. Your question will likely be closed without further information from you. See [How To Ask A Good Question](/sqrt(cosh^2(z)+cosh(z)^2*sinh(z)^2)).

Comment: You might also have a look through the related questions at right for how to solve your problem.